# How can you offer a bounty when you don't have enough rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422977/how-to-prevent-tomcat-session-hijacking) has an open bounty of 400, but the questioner only has rep of 16. How is this possible? Perhaps, if the system allows you to offer two bounties of e.g. 400 when you have rep 416, and one answer is accepted, that would reduce your rep to 16, leaving the situation as described. How does SO prevent this kind of "bounty on credit"?

If an answer is accepted, how will the bounty be paid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bounties get paid when they are started, not when they are awarded.

So the questioner had more than <strike>400</strike> 350 rep (there is a 50 rep bonus added by the system as pointed out by [@Workshop Alex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23603/how-can-you-offer-a-bounty-when-you-dont-have-enough-rep/23614#23614)) before he started the bounty.

Comment: Are you saying that the 400 is sort of "in escrow"? That the questioner had over 400 rep, offered the bounty of 400, and their rep got docked by that amount? If so, that makes sense.

Comment: @Vinay: Yes indeed, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Wrong! He had less than 400! :-) SO adds another 50 to every bounty. (Still, +1)

Comment: @Workshop Alex: I've updated my answer ;-) - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

He had 366 first, added a bounty of 350, SO added another 50 bonus and now has only 16 left. See his [history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554?tab=reputation)...

Comment: +1 for detailed information and the link

Comment: Especially the link is useful, since it allows you to see how someone gained or lost his reputation. :-) It also shows how important reputation can be when you want to add a bonus for a Q. If you don't have much, adding a bonus could mean that you have to give up all for an answer.